# Firebase dynamic link acting differently if generated on iOS (React Native) vs REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

We have a functionality to generate dynamic links to our app on iOS using React Native, which works perfectly (identifiable data redacted by replacing them with "our app"):

```
      dynamicLinks().buildShortLink({
        link: `https://our_app?referral=${referralCode}`,
        domainUriPrefix: 'https://ourapp.page.link',
        android: {
          packageName: 'app.ourapp.mobile',
        },
        ios: {
          appStoreId: 'XXX',
          bundleId: 'app.ourapp.client',
        },
        navigation: {
          forcedRedirectEnabled: true,
        },
      });
```

It correctly opens the app if installed, and App Store if not installed.

I need to implement the same functionality on web site, here's my code:

```
      const payload = {
        dynamicLinkInfo: {
          link: `https://our_app.app?referral=${referralCode}`,
          domainUriPrefix: 'https://ourapp.page.link',
          androidInfo: {
            androidPackageName: 'app.ourapp.mobile',
          },
          iosInfo: {
            iosBundleId: 'XXX',
            iosBundleId: 'app.ourapp.client',
          },
          navigationInfo: {
            enableForcedRedirect: true,
          },
        }
      };
      // generate page link and redirect there
      const result = await fetch('https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=OUR_API_KEY', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
      });
```

It's the same (with parameter names from React Native changed to REST parameter names respectively, as documented at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener)

A link is generated, however when clicked, if the app isn't installed, the page link redirects our website instead of App Store.

When I debug both links using `?d=1` query string parameter, I can indeed notice the difference:

[image]

(left: in-app generated, correct. right: REST-generated, incorrect)

Why are these links, generated with the exact same parameters, behaving differently and how can I make the second one work exactly like the first one (redirect to App Store instead of our website)?

Answer (score 0):

After examining closely I've found a typo:

While generating the link in the second example, I was mistakenly using the same key twice:

```
  iosInfo: {
            iosBundleId: 'XXX',
            iosBundleId: 'app.ourapp.client',
          },
```

Changed the first one to `iosAppStoreId` and it worked.